# Create CSS grid layout with pure CSS

Tags: css, css-grid

I trying to create a layout using CSS Grid like the image (any item is square):

[image: CSS grid layout pattern]

Code I'm trying:

CSS

```
  .grid-container {
    padding: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }

  .item {
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
  }

  /* Square */
  .item:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    /* 640 ~ 1023 */
    .grid-container {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }

    .item:nth-child(6n + 1) {
      grid-column: span 2 / 3;
      grid-row: span 2;
    }
    .item:nth-child(6n + 6) {
      grid-column: span 2 / 3;
      grid-row: span 2;
      grid-column: 2 / 4;
    }
    .item:nth-child(6n + 5) {
      grid-column: span 1 / 2;
    }
  }

  @media print, screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    /* 1024+ */
    .grid-container {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }

    .item:nth-child(10n + 1) {
      grid-column: span 2 / 3;
      grid-row: span 2;
    }
    .item:nth-child(10n) {
      grid-column: span 2 / 3;
      grid-row: span 2;
      grid-column-end: 5;
    }
    .item:nth-child(10n + 8) {
      grid-column-start: 1;
    }
  }
```

You can find my code here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2L0zcs5/)

Result show:
[image: CSS grid layout pattern]

I think use `position: absolute` with JavaScript that calculate the girds position can solve problem.

How to create this layout use pure CSS?

Comment: Refer this link: https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/ @Reginna

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try like below. You were almost good, missing `grid-auto-flow:dense;` to allow the item to fill all the spaces.

```css
.grid-container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
  counter-reset: albumList;
}

.item {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
}

/* Number */
.item:before {
  counter-increment: albumList;
  content: counter(albumList);
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) and (max-width: 63.99875em) {
  /* 640 ~ 1023 */
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  .item:nth-child(6n + 1),
  .item:nth-child(6n + 6){
    grid-area: span 2/span 2;
  }
  .item:nth-child(6n + 5) {
    grid-column: 1;
  }

}

@media print, screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  /* 1024+ */
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
  .item:nth-child(10n + 1),
  .item:nth-child(10n + 10){
    grid-area: span 2/span 2;
  }
  .item:nth-child(10n + 8) {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  .item:nth-child(10n + 9) {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the last item in fullwidth to close the gap above 640?